# Get XML Element as a string from xml data ( Search through XML data ) in php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

I am trying to get **11 xml elements** from a **'n'** number of xml elements. I have 11 ids where `id` is unique for all xml elements.

I am using php

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($j[0]); // $j[0] contains 'n' number of xml elements. I need to get 11 xml elements with 11 different ids.

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($j[0]);
$players = $doc->getElementsByTagName('player');
```

I need to parse through the below xml data(`$j[0]`)

```
<testsquad>
    <team name="team1" abbr="t1" >
        <tplayers>
            <player name="player1" id="1"/>
            <player name="player2" id="2"/>
            <player name="player3" id="3"/>
            <player name="player4" id="4"/>
            <player name="player5" id="5"/>
            <player name="player6" id="6"/>
            <player name="player7" id="7"/>
            <player name="player8" id="8"/>
            <player name="player9" id="9"/>
            <player name="player10" id="10"/>
            <player name="player11" id="11"/>
            <player name="player12" id="12"/>
            <player name="player13" id="13"/>
            <player name="player14" id="14"/>
            <player name="player14" id="14"/>
        </tplayers>
    </team>
</testsquad>
```

From the given xml data with 'n' number of player elements, I need to get only 11 elements.

I am confused with searching through xml data using php.

When I do the `var_dump($doc->loadXML($j[0]));`, I got the below error.

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input

Where I am going wrong?. Please comment if my question is not clear.

The given xml data doesn't have the header like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
```

Is that the reason, it is saying **Empty string supplied as input**?

Comment: " I have 11 ids" - just for clarification: You actually have a list like `$ids = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,...]` and you want to pick the corresponding player elements from the document/dom?

Comment: If `$j[0]` is above XML you **can not** have above error (or at least not referring to code in your example). In `simplexml_load_string` comment you write: “$j[0] contains 'n' number of xml elements”, so maybe you have to try `$doc->loadXML($j[0][0]);` ? (however, in this case you should obtain an error like “expects parameter 1 to be string, array given”)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)'s [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) instead of DOMDocument and I got the Simple XML Element object as a result.

Check out the below code.

```
$player_id_list = array(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21);
$xml=new SimpleXMLElement($j[0]);
foreach($player_id_list as $new_player_id)
{
    $result = $xml->xpath("team/PlayerDetails/player[@id=".$new_player_id."]");
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($result);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message says that you provided an empty string for DOMDocument::loadXml(). Validate that `$j[0]` contains the XML string, actually.

Xpath can be used to limit the result:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//tplayers/player[position() <= 3]/@name') as $attribute) {
  var_dump($attribute->value);
}
```

[Output](https://eval.in/543469):

```
string(7) "player1"
string(7) "player2"
string(7) "player3"
```